# Parallel function call in python with multiple input and multiple output

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run a function in parallel with multiple input and multiple output in python. For the sake of argument, let's define f as follow:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x,y):
    return x*x, y+x, x*y, x * np.ones((3,4,6,7))
```

Using map, I can write:

```
a = np.array(range(10))
b = np.eye(10)

l = list(map(f,a,b))
l = list(map(np.array,zip(*l)))
```

`l` is now an array of length 4, with each element being a `ndarray`.

But if I replace map with "parallel" map

```
import multiprocessing as multi
p=multi.Pool(processes=3)
m = p.map(f,a,b)
```

suddenly it falls apart:

```
  File "tmp.py", line 13, in <module>
    m = p.map(f,a,b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 387, in _map_async
    error_callback=error_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 669, in __init__
    if chunksize <= 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I thought map and parallel map are the same, could anyone please help me out?